# Keep a Firebase listener in memory when the app is closed

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-notifications

Can I run firebase listener when app is closed so I could push local notification with out use of back end to send notification
also can I push notification from firebase automatically depends on change of firebase in database
I ran it in back ground so I can push

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

    FIRDatabaseReference  *ref = [[FIRDatabase database]reference];
    [[[ref child:@"classes"]child:@"classA"]observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildChanged withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
        FIRDataSnapshot *child;
        UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        if (localNotif == nil) return;
        NSDate *fireTime = [[NSDate date] addTimeInterval:3];
        localNotif.fireDate = fireTime;
        localNotif.alertBody = @"Alert! from back ground";
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];

    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Firebase uses TCP connection to notify the devices that are observing a database path. And for that reason, Firebase can't run in the background, as Apple doesn't allow TCP Connections in the background.

So sadly, what you're trying to do doesn't work.

Comment: ok,thanks 
but my question now is there away to post notification automatically from firebase depends on database change,
notification from console is ran good

Comment: Oh, in that case, you should try using Triggered Functions on Firebase. Here's an example that might help you get started: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications